# How do I convert mm/dd/yy to yymmdd format in bash script?

Tags: bash, date, scripting, format

I have a date field from a file with 50 dates in mm/dd/yy format. How can I convert it to yymmdd?
I have seen questions similar, but going the opposite direction. I cant seem to apply it the way I need it.

Dates are saved in file as 01/20/72 and I need to convert them to 720120

Currently I have $bDate +%y%m%d as the command, but it is wrong.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string manipulation: bash regular expressions suffice here:

```
date="04/13/06"
d='[[:digit:]]'
if [[ $date =~ ($d$d)/($d$d)/($d$d) ]]; then 
   newdate=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
fi
echo $newdate
```

```
060413
```

If you're repeatedly doing this, make it a function:

```
mdy2ymd() {
    local d='[[:digit:]]' newdate
    if [[ $1 =~ ($d$d)/($d$d)/($d$d) ]]; then 
       newdate=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    fi
    echo $newdate
}
```

Comment: You are awesome. Ive been stuck on that forever.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sed` and its internal regexp storing vars like
`echo "01/20/72" | sed -r 's#(..)/(..)/(..)#\3\1\2#g'`